# Changing the default class creation directory Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have recently begun formatting my Visual Studio projects with the environment files (**.sdf, *.sln, *.v12.suo, *.vcxproj/.filters/.user*) into a separate directory, the build folders for Debug and Release runs in a separate directory and the src and header files in a separate directory, all included in an all inclusive folder titled with the project.

However it has become extremely tiresome to add classes without the class wizard and after looking through the different options available in the project and solution windows I couldn't find a way of changing this so instead of placing the files directly into the folder where the *.vcxproj file was it would place them into the *../../src/$(ProjectName)/src or include* folder depending on the extension (.h, or .cpp).

Is it possible to change this in the class wizard (*Project right-click menu > add > class... > **wizard***) and if so where would I change it?